# web - copy section to clipboard and remove certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive got a method which will copy a section of html to the clipboard to allow pasting elsewhere.
It is usually a table of which will be the main content so it will be pasted into excel and keep its formatting, which is lovely.

What I want to do is remove certain elements from this section.
The main ones are checkboxes and textboxes - which cause excel to go really screwy, and for some reason you cannot delete them from excel - you just have to start a new sheet.

This is the method I am using to copy:

```
$('#CopyClipboard').click(function () {
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('copyablecontent');
    var holdtext = document.getElementById('holdtext');
    holdtext.innerText = contentDiv.innerHTML;
    Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
    Copied.execCommand('Copy');
    alert('Data copied to clipboard!');
});
```

(excuse the horrible mix of jquery and javascript).

So I have my 'contentDiv' variable, I want to parse that and remove all inputs, and possibly other elements too (I could give them all a css class 'doNotCopy' or something).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
contentDiv.innerHTML.replace(/<input[^>]*>/g,"")
```

check the replace method here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

you may have to adjust the regex for your needs